I can't get Inbound Connections on my node
So, I've been trying to get Inbound Connections on my node, to no success.
I've got an UmbrelOS 1.1 installed on a RPi5. It's Bitcoin Node app is already set to allow Incoming Connections.
I also went into my router, added exceptions to the internal network's DHCP to the RPi5's MAC, and forwarded both IPv4 AND IPv6 TCP 8333 ports to my fixed RPi5 IP.
I also made sure that there were no Firewalls on my RPi5's Umbrel, not even UFW or something like that.
I restarted both my Node and router.
The problem is that, even doing all this, when I check bitnodes.io, it says that my IP still has it's port unreachable.
One thing I noticed is that the external IPv4 address my router indicates to be mine, is different from the one announced in whatismyip.com. This got me wondering if this is some kind of CGNAT problem. If it is: what can I do to solve it?
Thanks a lot.

Just wanted to update that my ISP does use CGNAT, so my external IPv4 is not personal but public. I'm trying right now to change that through contacting my IPS. If it does work after getting a personal external IPv4 address, I'll update this post with an answer!

Alright! I just solved it! My full node is now up and running! :D
So, there were two problems:

I indeed had CGNAT open by my ISP, so I called it and asked them to take it off;
Port forwarding on my router, for some reason, doesn't work with source IP 0.0.0.0 (?); so the source IP field has to be entirely blank in order to refer to "any IP" - which is something different from all the other routers I've ever had, by the way.

So that's it! Hope this somehow helps someone in the future! :D
